# jQuery ajax method doesn´t send request with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I´m new to jQuery and I'm trying to send a request sending data via json. This json just need to have one javascript variable value.

As it turns out, the `done` part is never runned, as the request is never made.
The problem is probably the way I'm sending data, but how am I supposed to do this in this case?

Here is the code:

```
    var myValue = prompt("Type the value: ", "0");

    event.preventDefault();
    var price;
    var desc;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ctx+"/addItem",
        data: {
            myValue: myValue
        }
    }).done(function(json) {
        price = json.data;
        desc = json.desc;
    });
```

I have a breakpoint in the server code that was supposed to run with the request, but that is just not running at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a tool like fiddler2 to see what goes to the server and the response. You may just be getting an error on the website.

Comment: I´m using a breakpoint in the server code, and it´s not running at all, so I don´t think the request is getting there. I was getting a bad request error in the Chrome debugger console, and even when I didn´t change anything in the code I´m not getting it anymore.

Comment: Maybe you should share your server side code, any routing configuration and what is `ctx`?

Comment: Check your network console to make sure the request is going out. If it is, it's failing somewhere on the server side, possible during routing.

Comment: post result in console with `console.log(myValue)` after the prompt, and `console.log(JSON.parse(json))` in done()